# How to access a JSON structure returned to jQuery via a ColdFusion CFC?

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am using jQuery 1.7.1 and ColdFusion 9.1

I am using a jQuery function to call a CFC that returns a structure. Here's how I call the CFC:

```
var jro = new jsMenu();
var Menu = jro.checkMenu();
```

Here is the results of the Menu variable:

```
{"ISVALIDPAYMENT":true,"ISVALIDWRAPUP":false}
```

I need to parse this in jQuery and am having trouble accessing the values.

The following have not worked for me:

```
var IsValidPayment = Menu.DATA[0][0];
var IsValidPayment = Menu.DATA[0];
var IsValidPayment = Menu.[0];
var IsValidPayment = Menu[0];
var IsValidPayment = Menu.IsValidPayment;
var IsValidPayment = Menu.IsValidPayment[0];
var IsValidPayment = Menu.IsValidPayment.[0];
```

How should I reference this variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im assuming you have parsed the response string and have an object literal.

`var isValidPayment = Menu.ISVALIDPAYMENT`

and

`var isValidWrapup = Menu.ISVALIDWRAPUP`

should work.

If it doesn't you probably need to parse the response to get an object literal.

Comment: Wow! That was easy. And it works perfectly. The case sensitivity that continues to haunt me.  Thanks a bazillion!

Comment: If you want to control the case, on the CF side, use quotes for your keys. Ie, don't do: <cfset s.name = "ray">, but do: <cfset s["name"] = "ray">

Comment: Mr. Jedi, that was a very helpful tip. I didn't even ask the question and I got an awesome answer.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Further on Ray's point, you can quote variables in implicit array/struct creates too. eg. `mike = { "camelCase" = "true" }`. If you do not quote the key, the cf default UPPERCASE keys are used. (Implicit array/struct creation is new in CF9)